# keyboard shortcuts don't let write in an entry Python Gtk 3

Tags: python-2.7, keyboard-shortcuts, pygtk, gtk3

In a window I'm using keyboard shortcuts, but the shortcuts blocked the entries of my window and don't let me write on them. I have something like this:

```
self.connect("key-press-event",self._key_press_event, b_finalizar, b_agregar, c_scales, b_buscar, storeCompra,entryCliente, l_total, entry, spinCantidad, spinPrecio, storeAutocomp, tree, l_unidad)
```

and the event method i have is this:

```
def _key_press_event(self,widget,event, b_finalizar, b_agregar, c_scales, b_buscar,storeCompra,entryCliente, l_total, entry, spinCantidad, spinPrecio, storeAutocomp, tree, l_unidad):
    keyval = event.keyval
    keyval_name = Gdk.keyval_name(keyval)
    state = event.state
    ctrl = (state & Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK)
    if ctrl and keyval_name == 'a':
        self.agregar_clicked(b_agregar, storeCompra, entry, spinCantidad, spinPrecio, storeAutocomp, tree, l_unidad, l_total)
        print "AGREGAR ITEM"
    elif ctrl and keyval_name == 'b':
        print "básculas"
    elif ctrl and keyval_name == 'f':
        self.finalizar_clicked(b_finalizar, storeCompra, entryCliente, l_total)
        print "finalizar"
    elif ctrl and keyval_name == 'c':
        self.buscar_clicked(b_buscar, entry)
        print "catalogo"
        return False
    return True
```

I need to be able to write in the entries and use the shortcuts, any idea could be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last state:

```
   elif ctrl and keyval_name == 'c':
    self.buscar_clicked(b_buscar, entry)
    print "catalogo"
   else:
    return False

return True
```